# How do I know if a url returns an image PHP?

Tags: php, image, curl, download

I have folowing problem. I use curl for downloading images from server. I generating automaticly name for images and downloaded it. Some of the generated image names are not returned image. How do I know if a url returns an image?

Sorry for my "broken" English.

Thank's in advance!

Comment: So you're requesting images from a server by generating a random filename and issuing a request to that filename? Won't that return a 404 if the image is not found? A little code would clarify a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$content_type = curl_getinfo ( $curl_obj, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Answer (score 1):

Vytautas' answer is correct, but incomplete.

```
$url = 'http://test.com/test/test/something';

$c = curl_init($url);

// Here you would want to set more curl settings, such as
// enabling redirection and setting a valid user agent.

curl_exec($c);

$t = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
```

After that, `$t` should contain the mimetype (together with some other stuff), except when an error occurs, at which point you get a NULL.

That said, there are 3 points you should check to ensure the returned data is of a certain type:

- file extension
- content-type header
- file's [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you keep streaming your data to your server like you already do. To check before you try to convert, you could use [finfo-file](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php).

A more complex way could be to set the `Accept` header when e.g. using cUrl to only get the response if the header matches. Example:

```
curl_setopt($cURL,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
        "Accept: application/json"
    ));
```

Or use `CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE`, see http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Using `Accept` is largely dependent on the remote server and the implementation of any application upon it.